# AngularJS factory getter and setter object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i try to make a getter and setter for the Supercontainer  object, but it dose not seems to work.

```
PrometeiaECAProModuleMain.factory('ParameterFactory', [function () {


var Supercontainer = function (userId, supercontainerId, bankId) {
    this.userId = userId; 
    this.supercontainerId = supercontainerid;
    this.bankId = bankId;
};



return {

    setSupercontainerParam: function (userId, supercontainerid, bank) {
        supercontainer = new Supercontainer(userId, supercontainerid, bank);
    },

    getSupercontainerParam: function () {
        return supercontainer;
    }
   };
 }]);
```

Comment: Question is low quality: What is the error? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use it like this in my service.js

```
.factory('CommonService', function ($http, $state, Ls, md5, $filter) {
var headInfo = [];
return {
    setData: function (key, data) {
        headInfo[key] = data;
    },
    getData: function (key) {
        return headInfo[key];
    }
});
```

In the Controller you would set ur data like this

```
CommonService.setData('Dataname',{name:bla, price:25});
CommonService.getData('Dataname');
```

So I can pass all my data from one Controller to another and have it available everywhere

Comment: I seem to get confused the more when people use the term 'service' then they go ahead and do `.factory`. It very very confusing for a beginner like me. Why do you say 'service' when infact you'll use 'factory'?

Comment: @OchiFortune `factory` and `service` are almost the same thing. Just think of it as same function with different name.

Comment: CommonService.setData('Dataname',{name:bla, price:25});    Here how to set $scope variable. Like, CommonService.setData('Dataname',{$scope.name:bla, $scope.price:25});

Answer (score 0):

Service example. Can access the functions with `ParameterFactory.getSupercontainer();`

```
PrometeiaECAProModuleMain.service('ParameterFactory', function () {
    var data = {};

    this.setSupercontainer = function (userId, supercontainerId, bankId) {
        data = {
            'userId': userId,
            'supercontainerId': supercontainerId,
            'bankId': bankId
        };
    }

    this.getSupercontainer = function () {
        return data;
    }
 });
```

Comment: This will throw a reference error at `supercontainerid`.

Comment: case typo in Id. had set it to lowercase :)